# Дошел до функций в Python и решил написать небольшую программку "Угадай число"

Tags: python

Укажите пожалуйста на мои ошибки и поясните в чем я не прав и как это исправить,проблема я так понял в вызове функции в блоке оператора if.Буду благодарен за помощь!
Заранее спасибо.
Вот код:
https://github.com/jeaved08/random_namber/blob/master/random.py

Comment: 1) нужен всего один вызов `random_number`, его результат сохраните в переменную и используйте в обеих ветках `if` вместо повторных вызовов. 2) False в этой программе не делает ничего полезного

Comment: Для выхода из `while` используйте `break` вместо `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде бесконечный цикл :

```
while True:
```

поэтому ,когда число отгадано и код возвращяет False цикл не останавливается.

Это можно исправить ,или используя:

```
i=True
while i:
```

и вместо False 
использовать

```
i =False
```

или оставите while True ,но вместо False использовать break.

Еще ошибки :питон 3 не поддерживает > ,<:
в функцию передается аргумент х который не используется ,
Число  каждый раз меняется из-за перевызова функции ,опечатка numder   вместо number и т.д Вот код под питон 2 :

```
import random

#Рандомное загаданное число компьютером
def random_number():
    x = random.randint(1 , 20)      #x будет хранить в себе случайное число
    return x
secret=random_number()
print("Рандомное число загаданное")

#Сторона пользователя
while True:
    number = int(raw_input("Введите ваше число: "))
    if number == secret:
        print("Поздравляем это загаданное число!")
        False
    elif number > secret:
        print("Число намного меньше,выберите другое")
    elif number<secret:
        print("Число намного больше,выберите другое")
```

Comment: Если сообщество захочет переоткрыть, переоткроет. Не просто так же закрыли)